# How to customize blank space between chapter title and text in gsm

Tags: spacing, macros, setspace, amsbook

I use gsm packages from AMS to write my book. Overall, the package is beautiful and works well. There is only one problem, that is the vertical space between the header and the chapter title & the chapter title and the following text is too large.

Here is a MWE

```
  \documentclass{gsm-l}
  \usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
  \geometry{includeheadfoot}
  \usepackage{fouriernc}
  \usepackage{esvect}
  \usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
  \usepackage{remreset}
  \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \begin{document}
  \chapter*{Preface}
  The vertical space is too large sometimes. 
  \end{document}
```

Here is the output 
[image: Output]

So how can I customize it? I want to change it locally, not globally.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can correct the spacings with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
% Uncomment the following for reducing the space above the title
%\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
%  {\top@space{11pc}}% old value
%  {\top@space{5pc}}%  new value
%  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\@dropfolio\bb@space{7.5pc}}% old value
  {\@dropfolio\bb@space{3pc}}%   new value
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
The vertical space is too large sometimes.

\chapter{Test}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

I've also shown the code for changing the space above the title.

[image]

If you want a “local” change, this is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\pretitlelen}
\newlength{\posttitlelen}
\setlength{\pretitlelen}{11pc}
\setlength{\posttitlelen}{7.5pc}
% Uncomment the following for reducing the space above the title
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\top@space{11pc}}
  {\top@space{\pretitlelen}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\@dropfolio\bb@space{7.5pc}}
  {\@dropfolio\bb@space{\posttitlelen}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\posttitlelen}{3pc}
\chapter*{Preface}
\setlength{\posttitlelen}{7.5pc}
The vertical space is too large sometimes.

\chapter{Test}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Doing the setting of `\posttitlelen` in a group is not correct, because of `\@afterheading`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me. I have another question, that is the space in the table of content is too large too, but it appeared with \tableofcontents command. How can I customize it? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: @Knumber10 It should be just the same: the two `\setlength` commands should surround `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @egreg -- it seems to me that the objection is to the spacing for `\chapter*`, not the numbered chapters, unfortunately, `\@makeschapterhead` just calls `\@makeshapterhead`, which doesn't give the requisite flexibility, the way it's written.  the patches you make do address that in a useful way; i'm taking this under advisement as a suggestion for a future update.